# Encontrar el archivo de ultima versión en sitio web con httpClient

Tags: c#, .net, http

Estoy intentando acceder a un sitio web que se usa de repositorio para almacenar las versiones de una aplicacion por medio de httpClient, para determinar cual es la ultima versión y descargarla, me podrian indicar como traer una lista de archivos disponibles?

Este es mi codigo:

```
        //CONSULTANDO LISTA DE VERSIONES DISPONIBLES

        List<string> archivos = new List<string>();

        //como cargar lista de archivos almacenados en mi sitio en la variable archivos?

        string archivoUltimaVersion = archivos.OrderByDescending(x => x).First();

        //DESCARGANDO LA ULTIMA VERSIÓN
        String url = "https://urlmisitio:4444/" + archivoUltimaVersion;

        string content;
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            content = client.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
        }

        string dest = @"C:\Programa\"+ archivoUltimaVersion;
        File.WriteAllText(dest, content);
```

Comment: Dado que no conocemos como está hecha esa web, tu pregunta es imposible de responder